# Clean and accesible Other option (Check box and text box)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, accessibility

When I have a set of either check boxes or radio buttons I often need to have an *Other* choice. This check box or radio button is very often accompanied by a text box where the user is supposed to fill out what this *Other* is.

How do you usually handle this set up? What kind of markup do you use? What do you require in your validation? Do you use java script for anything? For example:

- How do you make the form accessible? Do you use and how do you use the label tag, for example.
- Do you connect the check box and text box in any way with some javascript? For example, do you activate the text box when the check box is checked? Do you check or uncheck the check box automatically if the text box is filled out or cleared?
- Do you let validation fail with error messages if the check box is checked but the text box is not filled out, or if the text box is filled out but the check box is not checked? Or do you just consider it not filled out and not checked?

Very unsure how to best deal with this issue, so any advice and examples are most welcome c",)

Answer (score 0):

Typically when I have dynamic forms, I insert the input dynamically. That is, in the case of jQuery, I'll use `.append('<input...')` or some other similar function to actually insert the elements, and id it (or class it, depending), so that it can be easily `.remove()`-ed if the user decides they want to use another option instead. Validation is either handled via an onClick on an input button. If I'm feeling feisty, I'll go the AJAX route, and skip the `<form>` altogether.

I would definitely let the validation fail. They want "Other", and you want to know what "Other" is. If you don't care what Other is, then don't bother with the input box.

Edit: Might look something like this.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click( function() {

    if($(this).next().attr('name') != 'other' && $(this).attr('name') == 'other_input') {
        $(this).after('<textarea name="other"></textarea>');
    } else {
        $('textarea[name="other"]').remove();
    }
}
```

The `click` will react to any radio being clicked, and the `if` will make sure that it's only the "other" radio button that will react to the click, and that it will only react if there isn't already a textarea after it (so you don't get multiple textarea propogations).

On the processing side of things, you'll have to do a validation at first to see if other was checked, and to grab the input of the textarea if it was. You should probably use server-side validation for that.

Hope that gets you started.

Comment: Do you have an example of an Other input field "connected" to an Other check box or radio button using jQuery?

Comment: Is it difficult to make it look for `other` in the value instead of the name? Since in the case of check boxes and radio boxes, when they are in the same group, the names are the same.

Comment: Absolutely. In practice I probably would've ended up doing it this way. As it was, I was flying blind and just typing code that could work. It would look something more like `&& $(this).val() == 'other')`. At this point, the 'other' radio button is merely a way to let your POST processing know that there is a textfield it should look at, since 'other' has no other intrinsic or real value.

Answer (score 0):

I usually enclose my radio buttons in a label like this:

```
<label><input type=radio value=xyz name=stjames>Saint James</label>
```

this way the user can click on the text to trigger the button.

When deciding how to behave, I usually say to myself "what do you think the user expected when they did that..." and that often gives me the answer.  So, upon click or Focus of the text box, turn on the radio that goes with it.  This won't work if you've disabled the text box!

```
( ) US    ( ) UK       (*) Other [________________]
```

If the Other choice is a dangerous one (deleting data), though, I'd disable the text box until the user explicitly clicks Other.  Then, the Radio drives the Text Box instead of the other way around.  You want the user to have to go through another step in this case.  It depends on the situation - think about what'll happen in each case.

I usually try to make it impossible or annoying for the user to do something 'wrong'.  EG disable the OK button if something is inconsistent.  Or, select the Other radio when the user types in text.  If there's text in the text box but the radio buttons are set to something different, I'd usually just ignore the text.  But if it's a serious/dangerous situation, you want to make sure the user's made up their mind; if you delete the text when the user chooses a different radio, that might piss them off but it might be appropriate if they should be careful.